# Post form data with ionic 3

Tags: angular, typescript, api, ionic-framework, ionic3

I want to pass inputs values of sign up form to post them into rest API.
I make my API request in provider (user.ts).
I add my form data in the body of the request and Got a problem in pass form values 
to the provider.

My Template :

```
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col col-12 pager> 

          <ion-list  class="signupForm">

            <ion-item class="input1">
              <ion-label floating>Full Name</ion-label>
              <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="userData.fullName" name="fullName" ></ion-input>
            </ion-item>

            <ion-item class="">
              <ion-label floating>
                  <ion-icon name="mail"></ion-icon> 

                Email</ion-label>
              <ion-input    [(ngModel)]="userData.email" pattern=""  type="Email" ></ion-input>

          </ion-item>


          <ion-item>
              <ion-label floating>
                <ion-icon name="lock"></ion-icon> 
                Password
              </ion-label>
              <ion-input   type="password" [(ngModel)]="userData.password" name="password" ></ion-input>
            </ion-item>


            <ion-item class="input2">

              <button class="regButton" type="submit" ion-button full round  (click)="doSignup()" >Sign Up</button>

            </ion-item>
          </ion-list>
                      </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
```

My Componont :

```
          @Component({
              selector: 'page-signup',
               templateUrl: 'signup.html',
               providers: [UserProvider] // ADD HERE -> Also add in 
               App.module.ts

                 })
               export class SignupPage {

                  loading: any;
                   profiletype : string;



                    constructor(private UserProvider : UserProvider ,public 
                    navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, 
                     public authService: UserProvider, public loadingCtrl: 
                    LoadingController, private toastCtrl: ToastController) { 
                     }

                    responseData : any;

                    userData = {"fullName": "","email": "", "acc_type": 
                    "","password": ""};

                    doSignup() {
                   this.showLoader();
                   this.authService.register(this.userData).then((result) => 
                   {
                     this.loading.dismiss();
                    this.navCtrl.pop();
                    }, (err) => {
                     this.loading.dismiss();
                     this.presentToast(err);
                     console.log(this.userData.acc_type)

                });
                  }

                      showLoader(){
                    this.loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
                      content: 'Authenticating...'
                     });

                   this.loading.present();
                    }

                     presentToast(msg) {
                  let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
                 message: msg,
               duration: 3000,
               position: 'bottom',
               dismissOnPageChange: true
                });

              toast.onDidDismiss(() => {
               console.log('Dismissed toast');
                  });

              toast.present();
                 }
```

My Provider :

```
                   import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
                   import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
                   import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

            import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
            import { elementEventFullName } from '@angular/core/src/view';


           let apiUrl = '';

            @Injectable()
            export class UserProvider {

              userData = {"fullName": "","email": "", "acc_type": 
               "","password": ""};

                data = {

                "email": this.userData.email,
                "Type_Id": this.userData.acc_type,
                "Create_DateTime": "2018-10-02T15:18:10.715Z",
                "password": this.userData.password,
                 "name": this.userData.fullName


                  }


               constructor(public http : Http) {
            console.log('Hello AuthService Provider');
            }
              register(data) {
             return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                let headers = new Headers();
              headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

                this.http.post(apiUrl+'Regestier', data, {headers: headers})
                .subscribe(res => {
                resolve(res.json());
                }, (err) => {
                  reject(err);

                 });
                });
                 }

                           }
```

I am stuck in this problem and can't solve it.

Comment: what is the problem? is there any error showing ?

Comment: Api Request :400 (bad Request ).when I try to console.log the input values from provider i does not log

Comment: are you sure that the url to the post function is correct ?

Comment: yes, when I try it with specific value its work

Comment: your `apiUrl` is empty, where in the code it gets set ?

Comment: and also include the server-side code for that url

Comment: it;s local link

Comment: @Mohamadnagi, the 400(bad request) error occurs when the request lacks all required parameters. Contact the team who has developed that API and ask them to provide documentation for that API.

Comment: in addition to what @SujitKumarSingh said,  to be more sure of whats happening check the http call in the network tab of your browser, specifically the request body and the url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been observed that, your apiUrl is blank. Also need to verify data you are passing in your post API. Assuming everything is working fine(i.e. apiUrl and payload data in post api), only correction in your code will be adding `JSON.stringify`. Please update your existing code by adding below:

```
this.http.post(apiUrl+'Regestier', JSON.stringify(data), {headers: headers})
.subscribe(res => {
    resolve(res.json());
}, (err) => {
    reject(err);
});
```